# bsub not working with while loop

Tags: linux, slurm

I am trying to run the following command but I get the error:

```bash
syntax error near unexpected token `do'
```

command:

```bash
bsub -q XXX -P YYY -J ZZZ -R "rusage[mem=10000,scr=5000]" -R "span[hosts=1]" -n 2 -o lsf.out -e lsf.er  while read  -r line; dofilename=$(echo $line | awk '{print $1}'); content=$(echo $line | cut -d ' ' -f 2-); echo "$content" | tr ' ' '\n' > "$filename.txt"; done < input.txt
```

the following command is running successfully:

```bash
while read  -r line; dofilename=$(echo $line | awk '{print $1}'); content=$(echo $line | cut -d ' ' -f 2-); echo "$content" | tr ' ' '\n' > "$filename.txt"; done < input.txt
```

but the same command when joined to `bsub` option,then it is failing.

Comment: The syntax error you are seeing is because you need a separator before the while keyword. At first I thought you meant to write `... -e lsf.er | while read  -r line; ...`, but then you are using `input.txt` as the input for the `while` loop, so perhaps you want `... -e lsf.er ; while read  -r line; ...`. Also your example is probably `...; do filename ...` instead of `dofilename` but this is probably correct on the real code based on the message you are seeing.

Comment: this is not helpful. adding a ";" doesnt help [-e lsf.er ; while read  -r line]

Comment: `dofilename=` must be `do filename=`

Comment: yes thats a typo. its do filename

Comment: i could make it work after saving the while loop command in a shell script and then having bsub to run the shell script. still looking for an answer if i can do it directly in the bsub

Comment: AFAIK you can't pass arbitrary shell code on the `bsub` command line - but you can do it *interactively* as shown here [Write a job file one line at a time](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/spectrum-lsf/10.1.0?topic=bsub-write-job-scripts#v3614872__title__2)

Answer (score -1):

You need a separator before the `while`:

```shell
busb ... -o lsf.out -e lsf.er  while read ...
```

should become

```shell
busb ... -o lsf.out -e lsf.er ; while read ...
```

Also `dofilename=...` is certainly supposed to be `do filename=...`.

==

It certainly works for me using bash.

I don't have your bsub command, nor your input.txt file so ....

```
alias bsub=true
cat >input.txt
foo
bar
baz
^D
```

then

```
$ bsub -q XXX -P YYY -J ZZZ -R "rusage[mem=10000,scr=5000]" -R "span[hosts=1]" -n 2 -o lsf.out -e lsf.er ; while read  -r line; do filename=$(echo $line | awk '{print $1}'); content=$(echo $line | cut -d ' ' -f 2-); echo "$content" | tr ' ' '\n' > "$filename.txt"; done < input.txt
$
```

executes successfully.

Note that BOTH the semicolon and the "do filename" space are required.

Comment: Consider that it is the `while` loop that they want to submit with `bsub`.

Comment: adding the ";" doesnt work

Comment: Try the line ion the addendum.   It does work.